# LiveChart.WinForm: Column Series' X-axis not displaying as required

Tags: c#, winforms, livecharts

I am reading data from Firebase Firestore and displaying it using a Cartesian Chart. Here is the function that takes some data parameters and then draws the graph:

```
public void DrawGraph(double allowed, double denied, double pending)
    {
        cartesianChart1.Series = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new ColumnSeries
            {
                Title = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyy"),
                Values = new ChartValues<double> { allowed, denied, pending },       
            }
           
        };
        cartesianChart1.AxisX.Add(new Axis
        {
            Title = "Requests",
            Labels = new[] { "Allowed", "Denied", "Pending"}
        });
        
    }
```

Here is the actual output:
[image]

The problem here is that the labels "Allowed", "Denied", and "Pending" are not appearing as they should, e.g.
[image]

In this case, the data isn't loaded and the graph code is written inside the constructor of the parent WinForm. And when the data is loaded it shows the same results as shown in the first image.

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues couldn't find any definition of Points

Comment: Sory...you are using LiveChart not Chart...my mistake.